# How to mount TO-92 package on a heatsink?

Tags: sensor, temperature, heatsink

I want to measure heatsink temperature using [LM35](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm35.pdf) TO-92 package. heatsink is a flat surface of aluminum.

What is the proper way of mounting a TO-92 temperature sensor on a heatsink so that can measure the temperature of the surface of heatsink and also not fall off easily?

Comment: check this link: http://tech.mattmillman.com/an-easy-way-to-mount-ds18b20-temperature-sensors/, i think this is exactly what you need.

Comment: @ChecheRomo using an extra clip may bring additional Rth which may lead to incorrect measurements because there's no guarantee of perfect thermal coupling between the two metals. Instead, "fastening" *(e.g. via a glue-like material like epoxy)* the chip directly onto the heatsink will bring the best result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heatsinks do exist for TO-92 packages. Use the parametric search at your favorite components supplier and look for `Thermal Management` > `Heat Sinks` > `Designed for` or `Package Cooled` and select TO-92.

Here are some examples:

- Aavid Thermalloy [MAX12NG](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/2/Aavid_11192018_e13c527fd77d484bbe0764f7e440b753-1507237.pdf) (rail mounted clip for TO-92 sensors)
- Aavid Thermalloy [575200B00000G](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/2/Aavid-Board-Level-Heatsinks-Catalog-2018-1507171.pdf) (slide-on heatsink)

(The second link is less a datasheet and more a catalog.)

---

However, I think your question title is somewhat misleading. You're not trying to cool the TO-92 device (the LM35), but rather sense the temperature of some *other* heatsink with it.

The TI LM35 datasheet under **Layout Guidelines** states:

> The LM35 is easily applied in the same way as other integrated-circuit temperature sensors. Glue or cement the device to a surface and the temperature should be within about 0.01°C of the surface temperature.

Given that information, you might also want to look for **thermal epoxy** and adhere the device to the surface you intend to measure. MG Chemicals, 3M, Wakefield-Vette, and many others make such epoxies. With this in mind, you should be able to find application information and datasheets to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 3):

Among other packages, LM35 comes in TO-220.  This package is a better option for measuring temperature of a heatsink.  It has a metal tab with good thermal conductivity, and it has a mounting hole.  Depending which net your heat sink is connected to, you may need a [heatsink mounting kit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/227854/7036).

If you have a choice, use LM35 in a TO-220 package for measuring temperature of a heatsink.